# How to get mysql.sock file, mistakenly deleted from "/mysql/tmp/"

Tags: linux, mysql, pdo, sql

I was stuck with a PDO Exception

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2) in lock_may_be_available() (line 167 of home/../includes/lock.inc).
```

In order to resolve that I tried to recreate the symbolic link using the command. I'm working on the Linux server.

```
 ln -s /home/../mysql/tmp/mysql.sock /tmp/mysql.sock
```

when executed the above sql statement, there was no change with the PDO exception. And later, I mistakenly deleted the `mysql.sock` file in `"/home/../mysql/tmp/"` (not in "/tmp").

How do I get back or re-create the `mysql.sock` file. Any idea regarding the PDO exception and  how to resolve it.

Comment: restart MySQL (killall mysqld)

Comment: i restarted the server (server restart also restarts MYSQL right??) If so I didn't work

Comment: Remove the symlink, then restart MySQL.

Comment: so, do I need to redirect to the /mysql/tmp folder and remove the symlink??

Comment: I tried to do in both folders '/tmp' and '/mysql/tmp' using the cmd rm -d symlink shows the error "rm: illegal option --d usage: rm [-fiRr] file ..."

Comment: "restarts MYSQL right", - not always. In any case MySQL creates a valid socket at clean start. So make sure it starts w/o any errors

Comment: Does the MySQL start properly without any errors when restarted?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
vi /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

You will find the lines below top in your configuration file

```
[client]
port            = 3306
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Make sure mysqld.sock is where it is supposed to be I don't like the path in your error message "/tmp/mysql.sock"

Since you are here look for this line as well

```
bind-address            = 127.0.0.1
```

If you are trying to connect from a remote location comment this line out.

Try to connect locally (from a terminal on the server)

```
mysql -u root -p
```

If security is not a concern for you (i.e it's your personal server not a multiuser environment) you can also make sure the file is readable by anyone

```
chmod a+r /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

All the above should solve your connectivity issues.
To get the file you could do a fresh installation of mysql server.

```
apt-get purge mysql-server
apt-get install mysql-server
```

Or you can download the mysql-server .deb package extract it and you should find it somewhere in there. Equivalently .rpm if you are using RHL.

Edit: 
Since you've been copying files around maybe the file ownership changed to root, check that also (with ls-la /path). Owner should be mysql group mysql. Can't think of anything else.

Comment: my problem was solved, below I gave my answer. But, I think your answer is more apt to my question. Thank you.

Comment: oh yeah. After so many hours spending to fix this. reinstalling the server worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

I got this error after experimenting with the `CHECK` constraint in `CREATE TABLE` in MariaDB.

One of my *experiments* caused MariaDB to bail and tell me it couldn't reconnect to the server. Quitting and restarting led me to the `Error 2002` message. As root, I issued a `systemctl stop mysql` command, and then I started `mysqld` manually with `/usr/sbin/mysqld --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking`.

Upon restarting the client, it connected to the server. I deleted the database that I was working on when the error occurred with a `DROP DATABASE` SQL command. I exited the client, killed `mysqld` and restarted it with `systemctl start mysql`. When I restarted the client, everything worked fine.

I recreated my database from a SQL dump and went back to work.

Luckily, I was working on a small database I was using to learn database management, and it didn't matter if I couldn't recover it.

Answer (score -1):

Got to change the configuration file `httpd.conf` root value

Previously,it was `Listen : 0.0.0.0:80.` I changed it to `Listen: 0.0.0.0:8080` - changed the root to its higher value four digits (1024, 8008, 9999 etc) and restarted the `apache server` and `mysql`. Well, it worked.

And to My Question: `mysql.sock` file is a socket file it will be created automatically when the MySql server restarts

Finally, My issue is resolved.

Comment: mysql.sock file will be created automatically when mysql service restart as it is related with mysql service not apache service or server.